# Generates Duplicate Value in C#.net GridView

Tags: c#

My C# code generates Duplicate Value in Datagridview. My code looks like

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(818, 608);
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  CustomerCode, AccountNo, Branch, FirstName, LastName, Sex, MaritialStatus, MobileNo, Email, HomeCity from MasterTable where CustomerCode LIKE '%' + @CusCode AND FirstName LIKE '%' +@FirstName AND AccountNo LIKE '%' +@AccountNo AND Branch LIKE '%' +@Branch", connection);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CusCode", textBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtname.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", txtac.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", txtbranch.Text.Trim());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sdap.Fill(dtt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;
            sdap.Fill(dtt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;          
            connection.Close();

    }
```

[Duplicate Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CLwL.png)

Comment: You calling `sdap.Fill(dtt);` twice, why?

Comment: Shit, ya its the error..Solved TQ

Answer (score 0):

You are filling the sdap twice with the dt which adds the rows twice in the DataAdapter and on providing it with Datasource it binds with the doubled rows Adapter and shows Duplicate Rows.
Corrected Code -

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(818, 608);
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select  CustomerCode, AccountNo, Branch, FirstName, LastName, Sex, MaritialStatus, MobileNo, Email, HomeCity from MasterTable where CustomerCode LIKE '%' + @CusCode AND FirstName LIKE '%' +@FirstName AND AccountNo LIKE '%' +@AccountNo AND Branch LIKE '%' +@Branch", connection);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CusCode", textBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtname.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNo", txtac.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", txtbranch.Text.Trim());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sdap.Fill(dtt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;
       // sdap.Fill(dtt);    // Making the Rows Double
       // dataGridView1.DataSource = dtt;          
        connection.Close();

}
```